# In C#, monthCalendar update!

Tags: c#, monthcalendar

Does monthCalendar gets updated automatically at midnight in C#?

Basically, I am using monthCalendar's DateChanged event, so when I click on a new date in the calendar I get an event happening, but when I had the software open for 48 hours, the calendar didn't update itself automatically and therefore the event didn't work!

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Jo

Answer (score 2):

`DateChanged` event occurs when you manually change the date.  It won't automatically occur.

You should use something else.

If you want to know the date has changed I have one basic method.

You grab the date of the program start running with `DateTime.Now` and run a timer every 1 hour or so and whenever the timer is hit, check the date again and compare them. If they are not the same, the day has changed.